# Shutting down all VirtualBox (vagrant) VMs in one easy to use bash command (that can be put into a bash file)

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, vagrant

I use [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) for development. I forget to shut down a few of the VMs. When I go to log out of my host machine, the Ubuntu shutdown process appears to hang.

Might there be a way to script a close of all vagrant boxes with a bit of commandline-fu? Something like the following, but something that, well, works.

```
for f in $HOME/vagrant;
do;
  cd $f
  vagrant halt
done;
```

Comment: I don't know vagrant but it seems to be linked to VMWare, not VirtualBox. Are you actually using VirtualBox?

Comment: @terdon: Vagrant only supported Vbox initially. I think they now support other type of VM formats (understand VMWare)

Comment: @SylvainPineau ah, OK. I just had a quick look at their webpage and saw a "VMWare integration" link and assumed. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I'd take a look at this [script](https://gist.github.com/jphalip/6025225#file-poweroff-py). The full blog post is [here](http://julienphalip.com/post/43650456977/fast-shutdown-of-development-vagrant-virtualbox-virtual). Not tested

Comment: Richard please don't edit the answer in your question. You are free to answer your own question in a separate answer. I did give you an upvote for a good question.

Comment: Moved update to selected answer.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For a scriptable control of Virtual Box machines we can make use of the **[VBoxManage](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)** commands:

- List running machines (returns name and UUID):

  ```
  VBoxManage list runningvms
  ```
- Stop running VMs by "hibernating" them (reommended to avoid data loss)

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm <name|uuid> savestate
  ```
- Poweroff running VMs (not recommended because we may lose data in the guest)

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm <name|uuid> poweroff
  ```
- Use ACPI in an ACPI-aware guest OS (preferable to `poweroff` for graceful shutdown of guests)

  ```
  VBoxManage controlvm <name|uuid> acpipowerbutton
  ```

Also see: [How to safely shutdown Guest OS in VirtualBox using command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42482/how-to-safely-shutdown-guest-os-in-virtualbox-using-command-line)

### Update from OP

Based on this selected correct answer below, I've added this bash script "`$HOME/bin/stop-vagrant.sh`". So now I have something that can safely begin a stop of all vagrant VMs that I might have turned on yet forgotten about in a session.

```
vboxmanage list runningvms | sed -r 's/.*\{(.*)\}/\1/' | xargs -L1 -I {} VBoxManage controlvm {} savestate
```

### Command Explained:

`vboxmanage list runningvms |`  -- gets a list of all running vms under VirtualBox

`sed -r 's/.*\{(.*)\}/\1/' |` -- strips the string down to id number

`xargs -L1 -I {} VBoxManage controlvm {} savestate` -- runs the save state command on each box that's open.

On `xargs`

- `-L1` - take one line at a time
- `-I {}` - uses {} as a place holder for the next command

Comment: Whoo Hoo! Given the above advice, this command line works magic: 

vboxmanage list runningvms | sed -r 's/.*\{(.*)\}/\1/' | xargs -L1 -I {} VBoxManage controlvm {} savestate

Comment: Note, the `-r` option is unique to GNU Sed.

Comment: Best magical one-liner I've seen in a while! Good job! :D

Comment: On OSX/macOS, you'll need to use `-E` instead of `-r`.  It's the flag for using extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 26):

The other answer is great for handling Virtualbox, but Vagrant features its own mechanisms for handling Virtual Machines, and as was mentioned in one of the comments, it supports more than just VirtualBox, just VMWare at the moment, but who knows later!

This seems to work for me:

```
vagrant global-status | awk '/running/{print $1}' | xargs -r -d '\n' -n 1 -- vagrant suspend
```

**Note:**

This works with Vagrant versions after 1.6, for older versions, you should probably upgrade, but if you can't, one of the other options which focuses on Virtualbox may be better.

Comment: this is obviously a much correcter(tm) answer.  @Richard should consider accepting this one instead

Comment: The `global-status` command was [introduced in Vagrant 1.6](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/vagrant-1-6.html#features). Users on older versions of Vagrant, particularly those who've installed it via `apt-get` and may still be on 1.4.3, will need to update their Vagrant install before they can use this command.

Comment: BSD `xargs` doesn't support `-r`, therefore you may install `gxargs` via `brew` and use it instead.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 13):

My mechanism for this:

`vagrant global-status | grep virtualbox | cut -c 1-9 | while read line; do echo $line; vagrant halt $line; done;`

- global-status lists all boxes
- filter that for lines containing `virtualbox` (Filters out the help text, will break if you're using some other provider)
- Filter that to display only the first 9 characters (the global unique ID)
- While we can still read a line from that input, read it as the variable $line then:

  - Print out that $line
  - run `vagrant halt $line` halting the vagrant for that global unique ID

This is better than the Virtualbox method above, because it'll run any vagrant-configured shutdown mechanisms too.

Comment: This command works for OS X hosts as well. Others fail due to differences in command-line arguments handling between OSX and Linux versions of `sed` and `awk`. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewАндрейЛисточкин Confirm - works on OS X 10 well. Doesn't tested on other OS although.

Comment: The above command tries to halt all boxes, no matter if there are running or not, thus taking a long time to execute. For me, as i only use virtualbox, i changed the "virtualbox" grep to "running", to get only the running ones.

Comment: This is a good answer, but you may like to use `vagrant suspend` instead of `vagrant halt` to save the state and suspend for a quicker down and up.

Comment: True, and if it works for you that's great. I've had massive timekeeping problems with suspended VMs under Virtualbox, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but I'm wondering if the option [--prune](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/global-status.html)  is needed ? BTW this should be the accepted answer IMHO. Thanks.

Comment: @youssman: Prune didn't exist when I wrote this, I think, but I'd recommend running --prune on its own before the above to get rid of any that do not exist anymore before running the loop.

Comment: @Aquarion didn't know that (I'm new to vagrant). I think we can run it with `--prune` because it removes the invalid entries before printing the list. I'm using it now with `--prune` and seems to work (I'll post a comment if I encounter any errors/problem). Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 6):

In case other people get to this question: For those using VirtualBox, it already can take care of this, only involves editing a file:

```
# Contents of /etc/default/virtualbox
# ...
# ...
# SHUTDOWN_USERS="foo bar"  
#   check for running VMs of user 'foo' and user 'bar'
#   'all' checks for all active users
# SHUTDOWN=poweroff
# SHUTDOWN=acpibutton
# SHUTDOWN=savestate
#   select one of these shutdown methods for running VMs
#   acpibutton and savestate causes the init script to wait
#   30 seconds for the VMs to shutdown

## My original values
# SHUTDOWN_USERS=""
# SHUTDOWN=poweroff

## My current values
SHUTDOWN_USERS="all"
SHUTDOWN=savestate
```

The upside is that is not necessary to edit/create any logout or `init.d` stript to run the commands posted in the other answers. The downside is this solution is specific to VirtualBox.

Tested on Ubuntu 14.10 with VirtualBox 4.3.18.

All credit goes to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/491244/552).

Answer (score 6):

Combining some of the other answers, this will close down all running virtualbox vagrant boxes:

```
vagrant global-status | awk '/virtualbox running/{ print $1 }' | xargs vagrant halt
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

I just use `vagrant halt`.  If you run it without a further argument, it stops all the machines defined in the `Vagrantfile`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing scripts to parse Vagrant commands, it's advised to parse machine-friendly output (`--machine-readable`) which is more consistent.

The format is:

```
timestamp,target,type,data...
```

so you can import it as CSV file, since it's comma-separated.

With shell, it's probably more difficult to parse, for example:

```
for id in $(vagrant global-status --machine-readable | cut -d, -f5 | grep -B3 running | egrep -o "[0-9a-f]{7}"); do
    vagrant suspend $id;
done
```

See: [Vagrant - Machine readable output](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/machine-readable.html)

---

However I find it easier to parse the standard output, e.g.

```
while read id name provider state path; do
  [ "$state" = "running" ] && vagrant suspend $id;
done < <(vagrant global-status)
```

---

Btw. Theoretically `vagrant` command should accept a regular expression for the list of VMs to suspend as per this GH [post](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7221#issuecomment-207461749), for example:

```
vagrant suspend '*'
```

but it doesn't work and there is a [bug #7221](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7221) which is pending in order to fix it.

---

Related GitHub tickets:

- [GH #7220: Provide extra options for filtering the list for vagrant global-status.](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7220)
- [GH: #7221: Implement --all for suspend or vagrant suspend-all.](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7221)

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not work for you ;-) Works for me

## vagrant_halt_all.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  OPTS=""
else
  # force close if any arg passed
  OPTS="-f"
fi

for i in $(vagrant global-status | grep running | awk '{print $1}'); do 
  DIR=$(vagrant global-status | grep running | awk '{print $5}')
  cd "$DIR";
  OUT=$(vagrant halt);
  echo "attempted to halt $i: $OUT"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a compilation of working one-liners as of **September 2020**. Thanks to all the previous authors for inspiration.

## Halt all vagrant boxes

### Version 1 (shorter)

```bsh
vagrant global-status | awk '/virtualbox running/{ print $1 }' | xargs vagrant halt
```

### Version 2 (more robust)

*macOS/BSD compatible:*

```bsh
vagrant global-status --machine-readable | cut -d, -f5 | grep -B3 running | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]{7}' | xargs -n 1 -- vagrant halt
```

*GNU compaible:*

```bsh
vagrant global-status --machine-readable | cut -d, -f5 | grep -B3 running | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]{7}' | xargs -r -d '\n' -n 1 -- vagrant halt
```

#### Alias

You can add this to an alias for quick execution. Add this code to `~/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc` or your shell's equivalent.

*macOS/BSD example:*

```bsh
alias vagrantHaltAll="vagrant global-status --machine-readable | cut -d, -f5 | grep -B3 running | egrep -o '[0-9a-f]{7}' | xargs -n 1 -- vagrant halt"

# Usage:
vagrantHaltAll
```

## Suspend all vagrant boxes

Or if you want to `suspend` any running machines, the syntax is easy:

```bsh
vagrant suspend --all
```

I recommend using `halt` for web servers; it saves disk space and may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Because `vagrant halt` requires VM metadata (you run it in the directory with the file `Vagrantfile` & the directory `.vagrant`) it cannot be used easily to halt all VMs.

In some cases it is enough to halt all VBoxes:

```sh
myvbox-halt-all() {
  VBoxManage list runningvms |& tr -d '\r' | while read name uuid; do
    VBoxManage controlvm "$uuid" acpipowerbutton
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vagrant global-status | grep virtualbox | cut -c 1-9 | xargs vagrant suspend` will suspend all the machines created by Vagrant.

[image]