# System cant shutdown if Vagrant box is not halted manually

Tags: virtualbox, shutdown, vagrant

When I try to shutdown my machine, it "freezes" or it stays stuck on one point, where it can not complete the process. I get the message

```
unregistered_netdevice: waiting for vboxnet2 to become free. Usage count = 1
```

After some experimentation I have noticed that if I halt the vagrant boxes, this error does not happen.

```
vagrant halt
```

This is a new behaviour that started a couple weeks ago. How could I fix this?

Comment: Here is the [bug report](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/12264) for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to setup a script to automatically run on shutdown.

See https://askubuntu.com/a/564674

Create `/etc/init.d/vagrant` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash
vagrant global-status | awk '/running/{print $1}' | xargs -r -d '\n' -n 1 -- vagrant suspend
```

Make it executable and link it into the shutdown run modes:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/vagrant
ln -s /etc/init.d/vagrant /etc/rc0.d/K10vagrant
ln -s /etc/init.d/vagrant /etc/rc6.d/K10vagrant
```

You can test it by starting some vagrant VM's and then running the script as root:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vagrant
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Shame that we have to hack the OS to solve this issues. I look forward to this issue being fixed sometime (not sure if by Ubuntu or Vagrant Team)

Comment: This no longer works, see my answer for alternative solution

Answer (score 1):

Nick Breen's solution no longer works (as of October 2015, vagrant 1.4.3), as there is no longer a subcommand `vagrant-status`.

I used Darren Beale's [one-liner](http://bealers.com/2014/07/halt-all-vagrant-virtualbox-vms-one-liner/) in the `/etc/init.d/vagrant` file, and it works great:

```
for VM in `VBoxManage list runningvms | awk '{ print $2; }'`; do VBoxManage controlvm $VM poweroff; done
```